# Why is FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.Create protected internal?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I just wanted to use `MySQLConnectionStringBuilder` to build a connection string and realized that I can't do that, because I don't have access to the `Create` method - it is `protected internal`.
Is there a specific reason why this method isn't `public`?

Comment: to hide it when specifying `ConnectionString(c => c.<intellisense here>)`. Whats with `MySql.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`?

Comment: @Firo: Thanks for the comment. That's actually a good reason. Are you saying I should use `MySql.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` instead? Where is it declared, I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to hide it when specifying ConnectionString(c => c.). Also note that it doesnt implement defaultvalues like the ConnectionStringBuilder in the MySql.Data.dll, `MySql.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` which should be used instead.

you need a reference to MySql.Data.dll in your project

Comment: I don't have any MySql assemblies in my project, NHibernate seems to be able to access MySql just fine without...